# Разные версии библиотек

Tags: android, unity3d

Имею такую проблему:

Добавил в проект рекламный `SDK Appodeal`, с их `Resolve`r, при выполнении `Force Resolver` пишет `Resolution Complete`, но библиотеки не добавляются, попробовал заменить последний `play-services-resolver-1.2.72.0` библиотеки добавляются, но у библиотек разные версии, мне нужно одинаковые версии, подскажите что можно для этого сделать.

Связывался с технической поддержкой `Appodeal`, внятного решения не получил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В play сейчас какаято старая compat/support библиотека (точно можете посмотреть запустив gradle dependencies),  я решаю так - в блок android вставляю так

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
}
```